# Sending Pings raises Memory Usage over time

Tags: performance, memory, cpu, ping

I have a network program to monitor some controllers with a static IP. My program has a list of this IP-Addresses and I periodically ping all those addresses using a timer to check if some of the controllers went offline.

After some days the program hangs, CPU is at 100%. When skipping the sending of pings, the program runs fine. I discovered now that after every sending routine, the program adds a few K to the Memory Usage. So there must be something faulty in my ping routine?

```
Ping pgCheck = new Ping();
try
{
    stStatus = pgCheck.Send(arData[i, 6], 900000).Status.ToString();
}
catch
{
    //Ping failed, write it to log...
}
finally
{
    pgCheck.Dispose();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Comment: The Ping gets executed in line 4 of my example [pgCheck.Send(...)]. Is it that, what you mean?
Sorry for my amateur understandings. Am not working with C# daily.

Comment: is this 900000 the number of packets?

Comment: It is the Timeout in ms. Though a very low value did not take any effect, either.

Comment: Is the code above inside an never-ending loop?

Comment: You might try using pgCheck.Dispose(true) instead of Dispose() and call the Garbage Collector cleanups not after each run, but after a set of pings is finished. 15 min timeout for a ping seems a bit high for something that normally completes in a second, But it could be a memory leak in the code outside the above functions

Comment: Alright, will try that and will also decrease the timeout to 10 seconds

Comment: I was thinking  about possible reasons for the high CPU load and the memory leak which in C# should not really be happening due to the garbage collector. The first thing that comes to mind is belwood suggestion about the loop, do you check the array size before running the loop. Also you could try reusing the Ping object since the send requests will not be running together.

Comment: No endless loop, I checked it twice now. Reusing the ping did not help aswell.
Unfortunately, right now we are updating our servers so further testing needs to be delayed...